# how can I pop all array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

ı couldn't pop() every array list. at the end remain two array elements

```js
function ürünSil(){
    let diller = [ "Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Almanca", "Fransızca", "Japonca"]
  
    for(let i in diller){
        let sonİcerik = diller.pop()
        document.write(diller + "<br />")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to empty out the array? Perhaps you should be using `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

you can empty your array like this also:

```js
let diller = [ "Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Almanca", "Fransızca", "Japonca"];

while(diller.length > 0) {
    diller.pop();
}
console.log(diller)
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the array changes each time on `pop()` so when there are 3 items removed from the array , the present index for `i` on your code will be `2` and hence the actual length is also 2, so the `for()` loops does not trigger further.

The solution could be to preserve the initial length value and use that value in the loop:

```js
function ürünSil(){
    let diller = [ "Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Almanca", "Fransızca", "Japonca"]
    const length = diller.length;
    for(let i = 0; i<length; i++){
        let sonİcerik = diller.pop()
        console.log(sonİcerik);
    }
}

ürünSil()
```

Answer (score 0):

use while loop instead of for.

```
while (diller.length != 0) {
  diller.pop();
  document.write(diller + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `pop` reduces the length of the array, which impacts the times the loop will iterate. Instead just have the `while` condition check whether the array still has elements, without any `i`.

Unrelated, but

- don't use `document.write` for this. Use `console.log`, or if you want to add data to the HTML document, then use other DOM methods.
- have the good habit of ending your statements with semicolon. You don't want to fall for the sometimes tricky effects of automatic semicolon insertion.

```js
let diller = [ "Türkçe", "İngilizce", "Almanca", "Fransızca", "Japonca"];
  
while (diller.length) {
    let sonİcerik = diller.pop();
    console.log(sonİcerik);
}
```